# W3.CSS - Responsive Layout - w3-cell-row

Tags: html, css, w3.css

Just started using W3.css, and yet havent found a solution for a tiny problem, that seems to appear only on mobile version.

So made a responsive container - row, with 4 different width cells in it. When I have my phone on portrait mode it is loading the site as it supposed to. But when i turn it to landscape - only this container with the 4 cells - jumps back into "large/medium" screen version - cells lined up next to each other and not verticaly... (attached image to make it clear).

[Portrait mode - works alright](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdyFg.png)

[Landscape mode - only this container uses different width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/585r9.png)

[Back to portrait from landscape - same problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vidZn.png)

Any advice on this?

```html
<div class="w3-cell-row" style="width: 100%; background: #2D9595; padding-left: 3%; padding-right: 3%;">
  
  <div class="w3-container w3-cell w3-mobile" style="padding: 3%">
  </div>
  
  <div class="w3-container w3-cell w3-mobile" style="padding: 3%">
  </div>
  
  <div class="w3-container w3-cell w3-mobile" style="padding: 3%">
  </div>
  
  <div class="w3-container w3-cell w3-mobile" style="padding: 3%">
  </div>
</div>
```

thank you

Comment: Are you saying that loading first time in portrait is fine, rotating it switches the layout in landscape, but then rotating it back to portrait messes up the layout?

Comment: yes, that is correct!

Comment: I guess your problem is on an upper container, not this level. More code would help us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation of w3.css:

> Responsive Layout
>
> The w3-mobile class adds mobile first responsiveness to any HTML
> element.
>
> Used together with w3-cell it will display the layout columns
> vertically on small screens/mobile phones and horizontally on
> medium/large screens.

So this works as expected.

On the other hand, "the different width" is on both modes (portrait and landscape) and the problem seems fixed removing the paddings (3% , left and right) of the div with class "w3-cell-row".

Answer (score 0):

After testing this, my guess is going to be that CSS `display: table;` may be recalculating and adjusting widths on rotation. To keep things consistent, try applying widths in percentages to each `.w3-cell-row`, which should only affect it on 600px and below.

```css
.w3-cell-row {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 3%;
    background: #2D9595;
}
.w3-cell-row .w3-container {
    padding: 3%;
    /* table-layout: fixed; */
}
.w3-cell-row .w3-container:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: pink;
    width: 30%;
}
.w3-cell-row .w3-container:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: green;
    width: 40%;
}
.w3-cell-row .w3-container:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 15%;
}
.w3-cell-row .w3-container:nth-child(4) {
    background-color: orange;
    width: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-cell-row">

    <div class="w3-container w3-cell w3-mobile">
        adipisicing elit. Rerum
    </div>

    <div class="w3-container w3-cell w3-mobile">
        consectetur adipisicing
    </div>

    <div class="w3-container w3-cell w3-mobile">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>

    <div class="w3-container w3-cell w3-mobile">
        Eos, aut?
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you test the original code without modification?. What is wrong with it?

Comment: yes i tested it, it was working fine, u can check the rest of the code here: www.tfportal.hu/asd/index.html

Comment: Bjorn B. thanks i wil check it out, hopefully will work for me too!